# Ubuntu 16.04, how to downgrade perl 5.22 to version 20 system wide

Tags: perl

Perl 5.22 deprecated defined arrays. Got a cgi-bin that's not working as a result. How do I downgrade perl to 5.20 system wide?

Comment: I am certain such an answer can be found if you exercise your google fu  ... duplicate questions downgrade the quality of forums

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has Perl 5.18, and is supported until early 2018. No supported release of Ubuntu has a supported version of Perl 5.20. You can try pulling packages from Launchpad --it's your system-- but you won't get much support here when something goes wrong...because it's not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Checking defined on arrays in Perl is not deprecated but forbidden. It was deprecated since Perl 5.6.1 (releases 2001) and triggered a warning since 5.16 (2012).  It now triggers a fatal error instead.

Downgrading the system Perl is a bad idea since there are system tools which depend on it and thus might result in an error if downgraded. But you could install multiple versions of Perl in parallel and then refer to the one you want to use inside your affected cgi-bin scripts. You can use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) for this.